# useContext with immutableJS

Tags: reactjs, immutable.js, react-context

I have an Object of data that I store as my context. It gets filled with API responses and I feel like performance-wise I'm doing something wrong.
I tried to look into ImmutableJS but there is no reference of combining ImmutableJS with ContextAPI. Is combining them together doesn't give any benefits? And if it does do have an example of to how develop such a thing?

Comment: Before worrying about performance I would first check if it's actually an issue for your app. Adding immutableJS will add more complexity to your codebase and it probably doesn't worth the effort.

Comment: But yeah, I never used them together, but I don't see a reason why they can't be used together. I would say just save the immutable values inside your contexts the same way you would save plain objects. The benefit you'll get is enforced immutability and "faster" equality checking for nested stuff

Comment: @NicolasCastellanos I do have a performance issue. when I update the context it renders the parts where nothing has changed. I was just surprised to see there are no examples of using the two of them. So it got me wandered maybe it is redundant since context API is immutable in its own way.

Comment: Can you share an example of how do you have the context setup, how is the data structured on em and how are you making the updates?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you use context directly, add redux or pass down props through your component makes no difference to how you use immutable. ImmutableJS simply makes sure that an object does not change unintentionally and that it can be checked for changes with fast reference equality.

The problem you describe could arise from the fact that your context object changes whenever any response data is modified. Therefore it would trigger a rerender on all context consumers (see [caveats](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats)). I like Immutable and use it in a large project, but if I am correct, it won't make a difference, you would have to fix the root cause or handle changes with [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate).

I suggest you look into redux (or some other context provider) or show us code.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t try solving your problem by introducing a dependency. It won’t be a magic bullet.

From what you describe, your context object changes frequently and is causing your component tree to rerender too often.

Maybe try creating multiple contexts that are only relevant for parts of the app. That way rerenders will only happen with subtrees using specific context.